# How to make an OSX app use a sqlite database in the bundle?

Tags: macos, sqlite

I have an app that is intended to ship with a pre-populated sqlite database. I will include that database on the bundle. How do I modify the delegate to use that database instead of generating a new one?

This is my first serious app on OSX.

The current methods on the delegate is like this right now:

```
// Returns the directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.addfone.LoteriaMac" in the user's Application Support directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationFilesDirectory
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *appSupportURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [appSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.myApp.BotMax"];
}

// Creates if necessary and returns the managed object model for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BotMax" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. (The directory for the store is created, if necessary.)


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
    if (!mom) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return nil;
    }

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *applicationFilesDirectory = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *properties = [applicationFilesDirectory resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] error:&error];

    if (!properties) {
        BOOL ok = NO;
        if ([error code] == NSFileReadNoSuchFileError) {
            ok = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[applicationFilesDirectory path] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        }
        if (!ok) {
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    } else {
        if (![properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] boolValue]) {
            // Customize and localize this error.
            NSString *failureDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expected a folder to store application data, found a file (%@).", [applicationFilesDirectory path]];

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dict setValue:failureDescription forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:101 userInfo:dict];

            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    }

    NSURL *url = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BotMax.storedata"];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

The database file is named like BotMax.sqlite

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to ship a pre-filled SQLite DB would be to copy the .sqlite file into the Application Support folder before the persistentStoreCoordinator is initialised.

The below code just copies the bundled DB. There are some things to consider before using that approach:

- This simple approach only copies the initial DB once.
- It does not consider merging or migrating existing stores (e.g when you ship an update with a changed model)
- Core Data is using a new `journal_mode` since iOS 7 & OS X 10.9. This mode creates an additional file when saving the DB. (*.sqlite-wal). If the program that *creates* your pre-filled SQLite file was linked against OS X 10.9/iOS 7 or later SDKs, you'll also have to ship the .sqlite-wal file.
- Alternatively, you can disable the WAL journal mode in the app that *creates* your pre-filled DB by passing `@{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE" } };` as option dict to `addPersistentStoreWithType`

The following code is based on the standard Xcode template for non-document based Core Data apps:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString* dbFilename = @"BotMax.sqlite";
    NSURL* initialDBURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dbFilename];
    NSURL* workingDBURL = [[self applicationFilesDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dbFilename];
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* applicationFilesDirectory = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
    NSError* error = nil;

    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[workingDBURL path]])
    {
        BOOL result = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:initialDBURL toURL:workingDBURL error:&error];
        if(!result)
        {
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

objc.io issue #4 has a section about shipping pre-filled Core Data stores: http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html

Comment: I have used your solution and it works fine to me but when I compile the app and send the executable to another person, it crashes with the message "cannot find BotMax.sqlite". I have triple checked and the database is on the bundle, and is listed on the copy resources tab.